# View callstack of unknown error

Tags: 2007, web-config, debugging

I've set

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

in my web.config file, but i'm still getting 'unknown error' instead of the stacktrace on my pages. How can I view the stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting this error on sharepoint/wss specific pages, you also have to add following fragment to your web.config to view the stacktrace:

```
<SharePoint>
    <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false">
      <PageParserPaths>
      </PageParserPaths>
    </SafeMode>
</Sharepoint>
```

You can define a specific path in the PageParserPaths element, but this is optional.
Don't forget to turn off the custom errors after you found the problem (certainly for a public facing site).

Comment: I think it is worth noting that you may already have `CallStack="false"` in your web.config, so you may just need to change it to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The full range of things to do is listed on this page:

http://blogs.prexens.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7a299699-f8da-4559-920c-bda481608691&ID=8

You need to also set CallStack to true in the SafeMode node to see the CallStack you require.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in the following web.config file in addition to your webapp web.config file.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\web.config
```